# Developing an Angular Desktop App, where to start?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at the Salesforce dev site and searching Google and am getting more confused the more I read. Between various terminologies and/or examples that use things like VisualForce, Lightning, Apex, Force.com, ngforce, nforce and many others I am just not sure where to start.

I found an Angular tutorial but it requires a third-party service that handles authentication (I want to control this). Other tutorials either use VisualForce or have a bunch of template code that will not run locally (Apex) or otherwise seem to complicate the issue.

My basic question is, if you wanted to create a javascript based client that can authenticate via an API and simply make CRUD ajax requests that get and set JSON, how would you do it?

The closest thing to "simple" I could find is a SOAP API tutorial but that uses libraries that I can see no way to download or otherwise access (the examples use relative paths but the libraries themselves... can't find them).

Is there a recommended way to do something like this? A "current best practices" for creating a fully customizable CRUD javascript app? I've started several of their "learning paths" but none seem to really nail this down.

Comment: There is a complete Angular app here [metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub) that would be worth reviewing to see the patterns used. The platform's "JavaScript app" technology is [Lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/lightning) - you will find a lot more information on using that on Salesforce than on using Angular on Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE!

I can understand your confusion, there are a lot of ways of achieving goals on the platform but what you're after is reasonably rare.

There's a REST API which does everything you need, and one of the easiest ways to use that from Javascript to to use [ForceJS](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forcejs) — that will probably your fastest option to get up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A basic CRUD app is rare? I have already implemented that one but it does not permit authentication via an API, rather it only provides for a clunky redirect to a new window with a Salesforce login screen then then redirects you back to the app. It also has pretty inflexible requirements around the callback it uses... for example if you create your own app with it (outside of the demo the provide) you cannot get the post authentication redirect to work very effectively unless you use their provided "force-server". I just want something more DIY.

Comment: No, I just meant a desktop-based Javascript app is relatively rare in this ecosystem. Most stuff is usually hosted inside of a Visualforce page or hybrid mobile application. If you only care about Windows there is a Windows 10 SDK that supports hybrid apps.